# Percentage moon illuminated to declare a new month?

Tags: rosh-chodesh-new-month, moon

How is a new Jewish month declared?

Today, it is [precomputed](http://www.cgsf.org/dbeattie/calendar/?roman=30) but in the past, a new month was declared only when the new crescent was visually seen.

Today, we have software like [Stellarium](https://stellarium.org/) which allows us to see the precise illumination at moonset at Jerusalem.

**QUESTION**
What is the minimum moon illumination required for a new crescent to be visible and therefore for a new month to be declared?

Based on my amateur work, I believe it has to be greater than 0.7% but I would like an authoritative answer.

[image: Moonset, March 23, 30 AD]

Comment: I don't think this is a question about Judaism. Rather, it's asking about the scientific measurement where the new moon is visible to the naked eye, something which Judaism has no say.

Comment: If two very talented Jew spotted the new moon unaided at 0.000001% illumination, I'd think that counts.

Comment: It has to be  visible. What percentage that would be is  a scientific question that is off-topic here. It might depend on a variety of factors, but it isn't discussed in gemara or Rambam.

Comment: As per Robev's commented. I think the question would be more suitable for this site if it was: How is a new Jewish month declared? (as you write in the beginning of your question). However, please have a look at here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=new+moon since it might be a duplicate.

Comment: As others pointed out, the criterion is, Is it seen?, not, What does astronomy say on if it should be seen? *OTOH*, I'm wondering if the Chazal that Hashem showed Moshe a new moon and said כזה ראה וקדש is relevant. What did he need to be shown? Maybe he was being given a minimum standard. Just as we would not consider an insect a problem if it is too small for a normal human being to see it, the moon might be the same. Presumably you can't use a telescope or computer enhancement, even on a cloudy day.

Comment: Brisker Rav Parshas Bo says any amount, so long as it's visible

Answer (score 0):

No minimum amount is mentioned in the Mishna or Talmud - however it must be visible. What that amount is is a scientific question, but seemingly one with no practical halachic implications, as if anyone can see it it must be visible!

---

However, the Brisker Rav, [Shemos 12:2](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41469&st=&pgnum=30) writes that knowing the time of minimum human visibility does have a practical ramification, in the case where Rosh Chodesh is being calculated. Since:

- technically the moon begins to get bigger one second after the molad/conjunction,
- physical seeing is anyway not being relied upon here,

One might assume that this knowledge is good enough, and a calculated new month would be able to start any time from the calculated molad. However this is not so, contends the Brisker Rav - even in this case enough time must elapsed for it to be visible to the naked eye, despite not needing any witnesses or testimony.

---

As such, it is necessary to know the minimum amount of time needed. This is difficult to know, and indeed the Brisker Rav writes that this is what Rashi [Shemos 12:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.12.2) means by:

> Moshe found it difficult to understand the birth of the new moon, when it is visible and able to be sanctified. HKBH had to show him and say "like this - see and sanctify!"

---

[Rosh Hashana 20b](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9B_%D7%91) seems to indicate the time needed is 6 hours. This is also indicated by our calendar (based on the above argument), which allows Rosh Chodesh to fall on the day of the molad provided it is before mid-day.

The Ba'al Hamaor there says at least 24 hours are required for sighting, and he reinterprets the Gemara and the midday requirement to conform with this.

From the discussion in the Talmud we see another ramification - if not enough time has elapsed Beis Din would be able to reject the witnesses as liars.

Answer (score -1):

If testimony was not brought on day 30 of the month that the moon was visible, then day 31 is automatically considered the first of the new month. This causes the old month to be 30 days,

If several months occurred like this, the new moon will eventually show up earlier than day 29. When this happens, bais din will refuse to hear testimony so that the old month will be 29 days. This causes the months of the year to average 29.5 days and the holidays come out properly.

There are people who go to the hills around Yerushalayim to attempt to see the moon in order to be ready for the coming of the mashiach and the reestablishment of the Sanhedrin. However, this is practice only.

Comment: Is mashiach a prerequisite for kiddush hachodesh by witnesses?

Comment: People practice seeing the new moon even outside of yerushalayim. Seemingly it's still a mitzva to learn how not unlike learning how to identify kosher locusts. (I was unsuccessful earlier this week.)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @N.T. We see that when the witnesses were available and could see the moon, then the new month was declared. If they did not show up the new month was automatically declared the next day. If several 30 day months were declared, the month was 29 days even if it was visible earlier,

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer.